# 'Set-AzDataFactoryV2Dataset' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet in windows

Tags: windows, azure, powershell, dataset

I have been going through the Microsoft Azure data engineering course and in the "Data integration at scale with Azure Data Factory or Azure Synapse Pipeline / Integrate data with Azure Data Factory or Azure Synapse Pipeline " course It was mentioned to use code below to create a data set:

Set-AzDataFactoryV2Dataset -DataFactoryName $DataFactory.DataFactoryName -ResourceGroupName $ResGrp.ResourceGroupName -Name "InputDataset" -DefinitionFile ".\InputDataset.json"

When I run it with my DF name and RG name it gives this error:

Set-AzDataFactoryV2 : The term 'Set-AzDataFactoryV2' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
try again.

Should I install a package or something? What is this error?

Answer (score 1):

the error message indicates that you do not have installed the related module or that the install path of the module is not part of the PsModulePath sytem variable.

to install the module

```
install-module az
```

if the module is installed add the path to the system variable PsModulePath or specify the path at the beginning of the scipt:

```
import-modul [path]
```